# OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, rails-activestorage

I looked at every possible solution regarding this error but nothing solved it.

Every time I try to upload an image, I receive that error.

In `config/application.rb` I have `require 'active_storage/engine'` uncommented.

In `config/environments/development.rb` I have `config.active_storage.service = :local` set up.

I ran `rails active_storage:install` and `rails db:migrate`.

The name of the model is `user_test`

```
class UserTest < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

**I have this in app/controllers/user_tests_controller.rb**

```
def user_test_params
  params.require(:user_test).permit(:title, :caption, :image)
end
```

**config/storage.yml**

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

I am really clueless as to why it isn't working.

**Edit:**

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 111ms (ActiveRecord: 43.1ms)



    OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError - :
      (erb):12:in `<main>'
      app/controllers/user_tests_controller.rb:27:in `create'
    
    Started POST "/__better_errors/52f33e5e173d5e27/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-10 14:02:17 -0600
```

Comment: What's complete error message and stack trace?

Comment: @Vasfed I edited the question.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information here to answer your question. Something is calling OpenSSL, but from your files and the stack trace, it's not clear what that is. The first thing I would do if I saw this would be to check the line numbers shown in your trace. I can't do that without seeing the full files. From the information I see, I'm guessing that something is being encrypted or decrypted, and your key is either missing or corrupted. Are you using Rails credentials? If so, maybe check if that's working correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry for my bad english.

My solution was delete all code comments in storage.yml

[image]

And finally works.

Comment: When comments impact the functionality of the application... wow.

Comment: I had this same issue, and removing the comments fixed it. I still don't know why, but it worked.

Comment: How did the comments look like?

Comment: @jox like this, https://pastebin.com/6LY4e6cB